# Graph API: Retrieve all posts shared by a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to retrieve all posts re-shared by a specific user ?
I'm trying to get a list of all posts re-shared by my friends.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Graph API url `/me/friends` will give you a list of your friends and their ids. `/[id]/feed` will show you the wall of a user (where you replace `[id]` with their ID).

The [API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) is a useful resource, as is the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) tool, where you can try it out and see it in action.

Comment: I don't need to see my friends' own posts. I need to retrieve posts created by others, which my friends shared on their wall.


[Something like this example](http://i39.tinypic.com/20i8cqw.png).

Comment: aaah..that was not clear in your question. at first glance it looks like re-shared posts have a special field `properties` that indicates where the post was reshared from, but some re-shared posts don't show up at all in someone's feed at all. Strange...